# Jquery - Css background modification doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
                <div class="rating" id = "r1"></div>
                <div class="rating" id = "r2"></div>
                <div class="rating" id = "r3"></div>
                <div class="rating" id = "r4"></div>
                <div class="rating" id = "r5"></div>
```

Js (using jquery 1.10.1) :

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        var rate = new Array();
                        rate[1] = "r1";
                        rate[2] = "r2";
                        rate[3] = "r3";
                        rate[4] = "r4";
                        rate[5] = "r5";
                        var r = <?php echo $rate;?>
                            for(var i=1; i<=r;i++){
                                var k = rate[i];
                                $('#'+k).css{('background-image': 'url(images/star_green.png)')};

                            }
                    });

                    </script>
```

Basically what i want to do using this code is to modify the background of the first x divs (number provided in my db). I know that the js variable r takes the right value...same for the k variable...the only thing that i think is not working is the part where the background is set. I tested it using direct values (without the +k part) and it didn't work the either.
The page is located in root and the images folder is next to it.

Any suggestions?

PS: The Js script is placed on the page after the divs.

Comment: I think you inversed .css({}) with .css{()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a semicolon here

`var r = <?php echo $rate;?>`

It should be

`var r = <?php echo $rate;?>;`

Also

`$('#'+k).css{('background-image': 'url(images/star_green.png)')};`

should be

`$('#'+k).css({'background-image': 'url(images/star_green.png)'});`

Comment: There was another mistake. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var rate = new Array();
     rate[1] = "r1";
     rate[2] = "r2";
     rate[3] = "r3";
     rate[4] = "r4";
     rate[5] = "r5";
     var r = <? php echo $rate; ?> ;
     for (var i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
         var k = rate[i];
         $('#' + k).css
             ({'background-image': 'url(images/star_green.png)'});
         };

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

> $('.rating').css('background-image','url(images/image.jpeg)');